# MySQLi - Fetch Array and Prepared Statement

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to display rows from table but it's not working, it doesn't echo anything.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ?, 10";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if ($stmt->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $row_start);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

I have the code for old mysql ext and it works. Trying to get same result with mysqli.

Comment: Ridiculously, `fetch_array()` doesn't work with prepared statements. You have use `bind_result()`, which makes the whole process a lot clunkier. This is one of the major reasons I use PDO over MySQLi whenever possible.

Comment: @DaveRandom I thought MySQLi was an improved version of original ext... didn't know there is such limitation. I think I have to move to PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this below link:-

[Mysqli abstraction, fetching arrays from prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872064/mysqli-abstraction-fetching-arrays-from-prepared-statements)

The call_user_func_array(...) function just calls the bindParam or bind_result methods on the $query object with the given array, as if you had provided each element of the array as a method argument.

You may want to check the SQL statement you are having the problem with, with the code below. I've rewritten it a bit in order to make it fully testable, since the original code depends on the statement class in your abstraction layer.